# How to use android device as display or terminal?

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode

I want to use an android phone as a USB terminal/display for a headless system.

The ideal user experiece would be:

1. Plug phone to the usb port.
2. System starts sending status info, phone displays it.

I prefer a solution without developer options/adb necessary.

Ideally the end user only has to install an app and open it up.

Does a solution exist?

Comment: Maybe via [VNC](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_655)?

Comment: Gave it a try. Since the purpose is info display only, having a desktop is a bit of overkill and requires extra scripting to auto-open an info display. Headless system will have no X11 anyway.... Effort for the user to set up a new phone is equal or greater to the partial solution I list below.

Comment: Enabling usb-tethering programmatically seems to be not possible.

Comment: Good points. If the device is rooted, auto-enabling USB tether should not be a big deal for e.g. *Tasker* with the *Secure Settings* Plugin, as my [Tasker graphs](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker#group_950) reveal – just a matter of finding the right trigger-acction :)

Comment: Rooted devices are not an option. I want to be able to do a sanity check on the headless server using any device at hand.

Comment: Then I'm afraid chances are pretty low -- unless you find a 3rd party tethering app which auto-starts when detecting a specific device via USB, or something similar. If Tasker requires root to toggle that, there won't be an automated way without root.

Answer (score 2):

My current partial solution:

1. android: Use usb-tethering to create rndis connection.
2. headless: bring up network device with a static ip
3. android: ssh to pc
4. headless: pipe output to connected pts with write(1)